# How to stop internet router blocking connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, internet-connection

At a certain time, my parents are turning off the internet for my room specifically as I use a lot of bandwidth running a server, and not for any other rooms. They access the router, and remove my devices from their system, as well as unplugging my room from the router. Is there any way to continue having internet connection?

I'm not sure how the router we use blocks the connection, possibly by MAC Address. It's a BT Home Hub v3, and automatically blocks connections from my computer past 1AM GMT.

Comment: any wifi on router device?

Comment: Speak to your parents.

Comment: How do they block your devices? by mac address? You can always spoof your mac. But honestly, if you want consistent guaranteed service for a server, pay for your own business class line (it is often against the EULA for a residential connections to have a server that is connected to from the outside). Another note, maybe up the plan to include more upstream bandwidth. If this is DSL, your upstream may be miniscule and if you are running a server, all it takes is to fill up that pipe and the downstream goes down too - this option may make your parents happier.

Comment: `Is there any way to continue having internet connection?` - Yes, call up the ISP (cable/phone) company, purchase, and pay for your own connection.  If you are paying for your own connection, they won't be able to limit your access.

Comment: Emancipation - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emancipation_of_minors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a technological solution to a social problem. The only possible outcome is you get caught bypassing their blocks and you get in trouble.

You have two "Real" options

1. Talk to your parents and see if you can come to an agreement on not shutting your internet off. For example, not running any more servers from your PC.
2. Go get a job and pay for your own internet connection, if your parents see you showing the responsibility of keeping a job I doubt they would have a problem with you spending your money you get on your own separate (or paying for your parents) internet connection.